# Updating MKMapView to CLPlacemark returned from CLGeocoder

Tags: ios, mkmapview, cllocation, mkcoordinateregion, clgeocoder

I want to be able to update the region displayed on a MKMapView by allowing the user to type in an address or location in a UIAlertView. I currently have:

```
        if (geocoder.geocoding)
            [geocoder cancelGeocode];

        [geocoder geocodeAddressString:[[alertView textFieldAtIndex:0] text] completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
            if (!error) {
                NSLog(@"Found a location");
            } else {
                NSLog(@"Error in geocoding");
            }

            NSLog(@"Num found: %d", [placemarks count]);

            CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
            MKCoordinateRegion region;
            region.center.latitude = placemark.region.center.latitude;
            region.center.longitude = placemark.region.center.longitude;
            MKCoordinateSpan span;
            double radius = placemark.region.radius / 1000;

            NSLog(@"Radius is %f", radius);
            span.latitudeDelta = radius / 112.0;
            //span.longitudeDelta = ??? 

            region.span = span;

            NSLog(@"Region is %f %f %f", region.center.latitude, region.center.longitude, span.latitudeDelta);

            [mapView setRegion:region animated:YES];
        }];
```

My problem is I am unsure how to calculate the longitude delta.

Comment: You could just set it equal to latitudeDelta and the map view will adjust as needed.  But you don't need to calculate the span yourself in the first place.  You can use `region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(placemark.region.center, placemark.region.radius, placemark.region.radius);`.  Not sure about the second part of your question.

Comment: This appears to be working. I am assuming I will have to use a 3rd party geocoder in order to see all results that share the same name.

Comment: Anna could you add this as an answer?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You could just set it equal to `latitudeDelta` and the map view will adjust as needed.

But you don't need to calculate the span yourself in the first place. You can use:

```
region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(
             placemark.region.center, 
             placemark.region.radius, 
             placemark.region.radius);
```

Not sure about the second part of your question.

---

In iOS 7 and higher, the `region` returned by the `CLPlacemark` is actually a `CLCircularRegion` (see [Deprecated CLRegion methods - how to get radius?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21023307/deprecated-clregion-methods-how-to-get-radius)).

Although the original code will still work as-is, you may get a compiler warning that `radius` and `center` are deprecated.

To avoid the warning, cast the `region` as a `CLCircularRegion`:

```
CLCircularRegion *pmCircularRegion = (CLCircularRegion *)placemark.region;

region = MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(
         pmCircularRegion.center,
         pmCircularRegion.radius,
         pmCircularRegion.radius);
```

Comment: Unfortunately center has been deprecated.

Comment: @Andy, thanks, I've posted code that should avoid the compiler warning.