# Deprecated CLRegion methods - how to get radius?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-location, clregion

I'm using the `geocodeAddressString:completionHandler:` method, which returns an array of CLPlacemarks. I have to get latitude, longitude, mnemonical name and radius. While getting the first 3 is easy:

```
double lat = placemark.location.coordinate.latitude;
double lng = placemark.location.coordinate.longitude;
NSString *name = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", ABCreateStringWithAddressDictionary(placemark.addressDictionary, NO)]
```

I don't know how to get the radius now, as `placemark.region.radius` is deprecated. Any ideas what to use now instead? I can't find anything interesting enough in documentation.

Comment: New class called CLCircularRegion.  https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreLocation/Reference/CLRegion_class/DeprecationAppendix/AppendixADeprecatedAPI.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/CLRegion/radius

Comment: @danh How should i migrate from old region when i'm not initing it? Casting rather won't help and there is no method to transform old region to new circularRegion.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The deprecation note is for `radius` in `CLRegion` and it says to use `CLCircularRegion` instead.

Note that `CLCircularRegion` is a subclass of `CLRegion`.
`CLCircularRegion` has the same properties that `CLRegion` had (including `radius`).

This matters if *you* are the one creating a `CLRegion` with the intention of using its `radius` property.

However, here, it is the SDK itself (specifically the `geocodeAddressString` method) which has to worry about it and handle it.

In iOS 7, that method indeed handles it by returning a `CLCircularRegion` for the placemark's `region` property.

Essentially, you don't have to do or change anything here since the property names are identical.

This code will work from iOS 4 to iOS 7:

```
NSLog(@"radius=%f", placemark.region.radius);
```

Comment: Then i would recommend to use: `[(CLCircularRegion*)placemark.region radius]` to avod extra warning. Thank you for response.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately if the Deployment Target is 7.0, it gives that warning.  If Deployment Target is less than 7.0 while still using the iOS 7 SDK, there is no warning.