# Get right zoom area for CLPlacemark

Tags: ios, swift, cocoa-touch, mapkit

I'm using `MKLocalSearch`to search for certain places like cities or streets in cities to shown them on an `MKMapView`

I show the placemark like this

```
let loc = placemark.location! //CLLocation of CLPlacemark
var mapRegion = MKCoordinateRegion()
mapRegion.center.longitude = loc.coordinate.longitude
mapRegion.center.latitude = loc.coordinate.latitude
mapRegion.span.latitudeDelta = 0.03 // I choose 0.03 by trying
mapRegion.span.longitudeDelta = 0.03
mapView.setRegion(mapRegion, animated: true)
```

This works good when the place marks are cities as it shows a larger area at a reasonable zoom level. But when I want to show a specific street (which is the `CLPlacemark`s Location) in the city it is to far away.

Now I'm looking for a way to calculate the right span according to the "detail" of your `CLPlacemark` (Note that you don't know the type of the `CLPlacemark` upfront)

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: Have you checked this question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9164920/updating-mkmapview-to-clplacemark-returned-from-clgeocoder ?

Comment: For me it is not clear what you want to do. Do you want to know why placemark for specific street in the city it is to far away? Or. How to calculate span according to the "detail" of the placemark?

Comment: @Ramis I want to calculate the detail of the placemark

Comment: Code which you posted for me shown in the centered of the map with span. I can not reproduce or I do not understand where is problem.

Comment: I want the right span for the detail of the placemark. If the placemark is a certain street in the city then I want to zoom closer as if it is just the city

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Let me explain it fully.

First of all, you need to retrieve proper `CLPlacemark` objects.

If you would like to search for `CLPlacemark`s at some specific `CLLocationCoordinate2D`, then use this approach:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D theCoordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(37.382640, -122.151780);
CLGeocoder *theGeocoder = [CLGeocoder new];
[theGeocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:[[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:theCoordinate.latitude longitude:theCoordinate.longitude]
                  completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error)
 {
      CLPlacemark *thePlacemark = placemarks.firstObject;
 }];
```

Now that you got some proper `CLPlacemark`, you can use its `.region` property. Please note that documentation says that `.region` is `CLRegion`, but actually it is `CLCircularRegion`.

```
CLCircularRegion *theRegion = (id)thePlacemark.region;
```

However, `MKMapView` doesn't work with `CLCircularRegion`, while it works with `MKMapRect`. You can use the solution below:

[How to convert CLCircularRegion to MKMapRect](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27284833/5165668)

```
MKMapRect theMapRect = [self rectForCLRegion:theRegion];
```

Now that we got our `MKMapRect`, we can pass it to our `MKMapView` like so:

```
[theMapView setVisibleMapRect:[theMapView mapRectThatFits:theMapRect]
                     animated:YES];
```

Or, if you would like to adjust the screen offsets a bit further, you can use:

```
[theMapView setVisibleMapRect:[theMapView mapRectThatFits:theMapRect]
                  edgePadding:UIEdgeInsetsMake(50, 50, 50, 50)
                     animated:YES];
```

---

### Conclusion:

Code seems to work fine and adjusts the span automatically, using information provided via `CLCircularRegion` `.radius` property.

The picture below shows the result if you pass (37.382640, -122.151780)

[image]

To compare, this is the picture if you pass (37.382640, -12.151780)

[image]

Comment: This is the perfect answer - you totally deserve the reward! Thanks for taking the time - on whatever I looked or searched for I couldn't figure it out